# Create ranges based on common cell values and create matching range names

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a file with all data in column A. In addition, I have a number of unique identifiers in column G. I would like to group all the data in column A based on the identifiers in column G

```
Sub createRanges()

Dim LastRowAll, LastRowUnique As Integer
Dim x, y
Dim rng As Variant

Range("G3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
LastRowAll = ActiveCell.Row

Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
LastRowUnique = ActiveCell.Row


For Each x In Range("G3:G" & LastRowUnique)
   For Each y In Range("A2:A" & LastRowAll)
      If IsEmpty(rng) And y = x Then
         rng = y.Address(0, 0)
      ElseIf y = x Then
         rng = rng & "," & y.Address(0, 0)
      End If
   Next y

   rng_formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(x.Value,""-"","""")"
   rng_name = Application.Evaluate(rng_formula)
   ' This yields error 2029
   Range(rng).Name = rng_name
   With ThisWorkbook
     .Names(rng).Delete
   End With
Next x

End Sub
```

Why does the following not work in my script;

```
 rng_formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(x.Value,""-"","""")"
 rng_name = Application.Evaluate(rng_formula)
```

`X.value` is equal to `"2016-07-15"` if I inspect the elements. I need to remove the `-` because this character is not possible in a named range.

Thank you

Comment: What is the goal of your code? This looks like overcomplicated.

Comment: Could you please post a data example? the input you have and the expected output

Comment: The goal is to get multiple named ranges where each range consist of the cells that have a value that is equal to the unique identifier in column G. In addition, this unique identifier is also the name of the corresponding range. So for example range `20160717` consist of all the cells in column A that have the value `2016-07-17`

Comment: I think line `"=SUBSTITUTE(x.Value,""-"","""")"` should be `"=SUBSTITUTE(" & x.Value & ",""-"","""")"`.